# Mongrel (Tomcat plugin) won't work with Neon

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I had Mongrel working with Mars. Now I have upgraded to Neon version of Eclipse, I can't install Mongrel as it gives an error. The errror shows when I try to open the Preferences window, showing in automodules.activate (bundle.net.sf.mongrel.plugin)
Class NotFound 
org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.

Has anyone had success installing Mongrel on Neon, or had a similar error.

All in all, I'm not too impressed with Neon, as it made me install Java 8 (despite Android Studio wanting 7 as a maximum) and has no SWT window builder for Java and the upgrade from Mars doesn't work with the oomph installer.

I should have mentioned I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 (64 bit)

Comment: I had the same error. Good to know it isn't just me. I'm on a Mac so it isn't an OS problem. Also, I had Tomcat and Eclipse running with Java 8 on Mars so it isn't that you had to upgrade to Java 8 either.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer [via a comment on my blog post](https://www.selikoff.net/2016/06/24/mongrel-tomcat-launcher-not-working-on-neon/) complaining about the issue. There's now a plugin called "Eclipse Tomcat Plugin 9.1.0". It works in Neon and it looks just like Mongrel used to do.